# Increasing Python Opencv knnmatch number of cores

Tags: python, opencv

I am using the python opencv matcher.knnmatch function in my project on an Ipython notebook. When I execute the function I notice (running htop in my linux machine) that only uses 8 of my 40 cores to do the matching. Is there anyway knnmatch uses all the cores?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of matcher are you using? BFMatcher, FlannMatcher, ... ?